# Increment value of a column field whenever SELECT row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

So I have this function that works very nicely to update the count of views on a product:

```
UPDATE products SET view=view+1 WHERE id=@id RETURNING *
```

The problem is that I am currently switching my users to read-only to add more security. Unfortunately, as this function updates the number of view, it is not possible, since it is an update operation.

So I was wondering if there is any way that PSQL would allow me to create a trigger function that update column value each time data is queried ? I looked at the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html) but did not notice any example related to my usecase.

Perhaps something like this (pseudo-code):

```
CREATE TRIGGER view_increment
    AFTER SELECT ON products WHERE id=@id
    EXECUTE SET view=view+1;
```

Comment: Documentation says that `select` triggers are not possible.  Perhaps somebody else will have a better solution for you, but if you are doing this in response to an audit or by direction of a security architect, my suggestion is to create a `product_views` table with an FK back to `products` and `grant update` on it to your otherwise read-only user.  Present it as a mitigating control to protect the main `products` table while retaining the ability to track views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is to create a function that is created with `security definer` as a user that has write privileges on the database. Then the function is used instead of the table:

```
create function get_product(p_product_id integer)
  returns products --<< returns a complete row
as
$$
  update products 
    set "view" = "view" + 1;
  select *
  from product
  where id = p_product_id;
$$
language sql
volatile
security definer; --<< runs with the privileges of the owner
```

Then the use it like this:

```
select *
from get_product(42);
```

If you want to allow to view multiple products you can change the function to `returns setof product`

Comment: Well, you need to replace it with the name of your table.

Comment: ok there was a slight typo that is why I was confused. The function was created successfully but when I tried to call it I got 'ERROR:  UPDATE is not allowed in a non-volatile function'

Comment: ALTER FUNCTION get_product(p_product_id integer) VOLATILE;

Comment: I accepted your answer after editing 'STABLE' to 'VOLATILE', thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to have `SELECT` on `products` operate through a function:

```
SELECT * product_item(id);
```

And have product_item() do the `UPDATE`, where product_item() would have `SECURITY DEFINER` set so it can run as privileged user.

Comment: Thank you for the short answer that was indeed the solution!